# How to populate a GridView column with current user

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I’m having some trouble figuring this out. Hopefully someone on here can tell me what I’m doing wrong.
I am trying to populate a “userName” column in a Gridview with the current logged in user. My end goal is to populate that “userName” column in a database with the user that edited the “userEntry” column in the same Gridview. I want to know who made a change and log that user in the “userName” column of the database table “userEntry”.

Here’s what I have.
I created a sample database (sampleDB) and inside the database I created a simple table, “userEntry”.
See sample db script below.

```
USE sampleDB;
GO

CREATE TABLE userEntry(
    id INT IDENTITY
    , someText VARCHAR(20)
    , userName VARCHAR(20)
    );
GO

INSERT INTO userEntry(someText, userName)
VALUES('Hello', 'John')
, ('Ohla', 'Sam');
GO

SELECT *
FROM userEntry;
GO
```

Next, I created a simple ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) called “getUser1”. Then I added a GridView  and a SQL connection string to link to the GridView to the database table.
Here is the code I am using in the ASP.NET Web Application.

**Default.aspx Page:**

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="getUser1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">


   <div>
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="id" Width="328px">
           <Columns>                
               <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />               
               <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
               <asp:BoundField DataField="someText" HeaderText="someText" SortExpression="someText" />
               <asp:BoundField DataField="userName" HeaderText="userName" SortExpression="userName" />
           </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>

       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conString %>" 
           SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [userEntry]"
           UpdateCommand="UPDATE [userEntry] Set [someText]=@someText, [userName]=@userName Where [id]=@id"
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [userEntry] Where [id]=@id"></asp:SqlDataSource>
   </div>

</asp:Content>
```

**Default.aspx.cs Page:**

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Security.Principal;
    namespace getUser1
    {
        public partial class _Default : Page
        {
            public object DataField { get; private set; }
    
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    DataField.userName.Text = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

**Web.config Page:**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="conString" connectionString="Data Source=dsouthres18v;Initial Catalog=sampleDB;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

So, this is what I have tried (adding the "if (!IsPostBack)" section to the code behind for the "Default.aspx" page. But it doesn't seem to be working. Obviously I have no idea how to get the user in the “userName” column when the GridView is edited by a user and they click the “update” button in GridView.

I can get this to work on a simple text box creating a new entry, but I can't figure out to do the same with an "asp:BoundField DataField" in a GridView.
I hope that makes sense and I hope someone can get me on the right track to figure this out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, right click on the Gridview in the design view , bring up property sheet.

This one:

[image]

You can double click in that area to create a event.

Then, say this code:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        // string strCurrentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        string strcurrentUser = "zoo";
        e.NewValues["userName"] = strcurrentUser;

    }
```

Comment: This would be work! great answer with brief describe.

Comment: Albert, your solution worked just fine. 
I tweaked it a little to enter the “current logged in” user instead of the “zoo” value by replacing “zoo” with “WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name”
Then I added a using statement “using System.Web.UI.WebControls;” and all went well. 
Thank you for the response.

Comment: Okay, let's take this a step further. Is it possible to do the same as above, update the "userName" column with the current user during a row delete? I want to replace the current user in that column with the user name that is doing the delete. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you deleting the row, then you don't have a row to save, and thus I don't see where and how you can save some data in the row that is being deleted? Perhaps you mean you might have some kind of table log or table that tracks who deleted a row, but I fail to see how you can save some "user" in a row that is about to be deleted?

Comment: Yea, there in lies the problem. I need some way to update the "userName" column with the current user prior to the delete process executing when the user clicks the delete button. Kind of a two step process. First, update the column, Second, delete the row with the new values.  I can't do it at the database level, going through a couple of hops, netscaler, etc. and the user credentials get lost along the way.

Comment: But you still not defined where we are to save this data? I mean, we can't be talking about a context of deleting a row, and trying to save data in that row we just deleted. As I stated, if you want to write out to some other log table that the user just deleted this row fine, but I am massive falling to figure out a narrative as to why you would want to be put a user name in a row that you are about to delete - there is no need nor logical goal to do so? You can easy wire up some code in the delete row event that ALSO writes out to some log table, but you have to be crystal clear on this goal

Comment: I tried to give a full explanation but there was not enough room in this comment box. However, I have possibly figured out what I need to do. Create a stored procedure to handle the update in my audit table. Thank you for all your help thus far.

Comment: No problem - it just was confusing. I am sure that you going to update some other table with that information - not the row you are about to delete - good luck!